# FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES

Tags: android, android-intent, github, flags

I have just started with android.
while going through code on GitHub, for sending a broadcast, I came across

```
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
```

I am unable to understand the functionality of the above statement..if someone could help, it would be really nice.
Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review the [Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include relevant code so people get the context of what you're asking and please *search and research* your question before you post.

Answer (score 3):

You would normally use that flag if the application that receives the intent has never been started.

Here is an example.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.Intent");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you install an app on your device it is in "stopped" state, so the app component (activities, receivers etc.) will not respond to intents unless you either first time launch the app (to exist "stopped" state ) or add the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag.

Answer (score 1):

From the API guide:

[Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)

> "If set, this intent will always match any components in packages that
>   are currently stopped."