# IntentService sends broadcast to Receiver, but it does not invoke the onReceive()

Tags: android

I am trying to send an intent from my MainActivity to a service, and from that service I start a broadcast Intent to a BroadcastReceiver. The first intent is fired and is received by the service. The broadcast intent in the service is fired, but it is not received by the BroadcastReceiver

The following is what I have done:

- Configure AndroidManifest.xml to have details of service and receiver
- Register the BroadcastReceiver in the service

BroadcastReceiver code:

```java
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside onReceive of myReceiver: " + intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction() == "com.utils.myapp.MY_STUFF")
        {
           // Do something here
        }
    }
```

Service code:

```java
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    private static BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

...

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside onHandleIntent() of service");
        String action = intent.getStringExtra("ACTION");
        Log.i(TAG, "ACTION: " + action);
        if (action == "FIRE_INTENT_TO_RECEIVER")
        {
            Intent rec_intent = new Intent("com.utils.myapp.MY_STUFF");
            sendBroadcast(rec_intent);
        }
    }
```

In main activity:

```java
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("ACTION", "FIRE_INTENT_TO_RECEIVER");
        this.startService(serviceIntent);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```java
       <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FIRE_INTENT_TO_RECEIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

       <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:priority="2147483647">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Some actions here-->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Expected result: The onReceive() in the BroadcastReceiver should be reached
Actual result: The onReceive() is not reached

Comment: Your receiver is missing the proper `category` name in the `intent-filter` part

Comment: *Actual result: The onReceive() is not reached* Well, according to official documentation this is expected result (at least with >= oreo )

Comment: You need to explicitly specify target component of your broadcast with `new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);`. Implicit broadcasts will be dropped since Oreo.

Comment: first i would pay more attention on lines like: `if (action == "FIRE_INTENT_TO_RECEIVER") {...`

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
Try this to send broadcast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the error is happening because your are sending a implicit intent (you don't specify `MyReceiver.class` as target for your broadcast). Also, you must register the action `com.utils.myapp.MY_STUFF` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Sending the Broadcast:

```
Intent rec_intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
rec_intent.setAction("com.utils.myapp.MY_STUFF");
sendBroadcast(rec_intent);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:priority="2147483647">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.utils.myapp.MY_STUFF" /> <!-- Add this line -->
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks W0rmh0le. Will try this out today evening and let you know what happens

Comment: Will also have proper category name in intent filter section in manifest. Will update once I reach home

Comment: You can remove category for receivers.. Add the action only. I hope it works!

Comment: Thanks W0rmh0le. It worked. I am now able to fire up the intent to the receiver from the service. I just have one query. My service needs to be up even when the app is terminated (using swipe). I tried enabling autoStart for my service, but it still is not able to fire intents when app is down

Comment: Added flag FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to broadcast intent as mentioned in this place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546453/flag-include-stopped-packages, but it still does not help

Comment: I guess it is a problem with your service. It is probably not running. IntentService usually handle intents and finish. I guess you should search more info about keep a service/Job to keep running whole time

Comment: Hi W0rmh0le, I tried making the service a normal service (not Intent service). With this I am able to get the intents fired to receiver, but the intents are not being fired when the app is off. I checked that the service is not running when app is swiped and removed from taskbar. I even added a android:process attribute to the Manifest.xml for the service, but with no use